# GTK themes not working on Qt5 apps

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, gtk, qt5

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.1 right now (w/ XFCE4).  I do a lot of Qt5 application development.  Right now the applications that I'm making aren't matching the GTK theme that I have set (which is "Greybird."), it's giving me the "Raleigh," theme.  While this doesn't stop my development, this does drive me nuts.

I have another laptop with Xubuntu 16.04.1 (also XFCE4) that runs the same application, but with my GTK themes working properly.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with LyX 2.1.4 on Xubuntu 16.04.1.  There appears to be various solutions to this:

1. Some suggest running the application with the `-style gtk+` or `-style gtk` flags on the command line.
2. Others suggest setting the environment variable `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` to either `GTK`, or `GTK2`, or `GTK3`.
3. What worked for me personally was to edit `~/.config/Trolltech.conf` (or `/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf`) and add the following:

   ```
   [qt]
   style=GTK+
   ```

Further [discussion](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_QT_and_GTK_Applications) on the ArchWiki.